# plot number of data points in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using the following in R to generate a Boxplot out of a given set of data:

```
ggplot(data = daten, aes(x=Bodentyp, y=Fracht)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Bewirtschaftungsform))
```

Now I want to display the number of data points going into each category of the column "Bodentyp". How do I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you exactly want to have (perhaps some data and/or the expected (visual) output would help), but does adding `geom_jitter(aes(colour = Bewirtschaftungsform))` do what you like to have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fun.data`to apply a function (`f`) to the grouped data to return a count (`length(y)`) and a position for the label (`median(y)`)

```
f <- function(y) 
    c(label=length(y), y=median(y))

library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw() +
  stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="text", vjust=-0.5, col="blue")
```

[image]